# Member variable does not save value added to it from member from functiion

Tags: c++, class, constructor

Hello I have a small problem, I am trying to assign value to some member variable of my class from a member function. Everything seems fine but once my program is returns to EAN::read(...); there are weird characters now in the member variable -->"╠╠╠╠╠╠". Anyone can explain to me what im doing wrong? Thank you.

```
///My class ////
   class EAN
{
char string[13];
char strStyle[18];
char styles[2];
char area[6];
char publisher[8];
char title[8];
bool registered;

public:
///and member functions here//
};

////First member function that is called///
bool EAN::read(std::istream& is, const Prefix& list){
char str[13];
bool keepgoing = false;
do{
    cout << "Enter a EAN(0 to quit): ";
    is >> str;
    if (str == nullptr || strlen(str) < 13){
        keepgoing = false;
        registered = false;
    }
    else{
            keepgoing = true;
            EAN(str, list); ///this is where member variable will be assigned//
            registered = true;  
            std::cout << "this is area" << area << endl; 


    }
} while (keepgoing == false);


return keepgoing;
}

////////Here is the constructor that assigns the values to member variable//
EAN::EAN(const char* str, const Prefix& list){
int keepgoing = 0, j = 3, i = 0;

string[13] = '\0';
strStyle[18] = '\0';
area[6] = '\0';
publisher[8] = '\0';
title[8] = '\0';


if (isValid(str) == 1 && str[0] == '9' && str[1] == '7'|| str[2] == '8' || str[2] == '9') {
        keepgoing = 1;
        strcpy(string, str);
        if (isRegistered(list) == true){

            char _area[6];
            int lengthArea = 0;

            while (i < 5) {
                _area[i] = str[j];
                _area[i + 1] = '\0';
                if (list.isRegistered(atoi(_area))) {
                    strcpy(area, _area); **<--- ///assign value to member variable.///**
                    lengthArea = strlen(area);
                    i = 6; // exit loop
                    keepgoing = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    i++;
                    j++;
                }
            }

  .......more coding pretty same as above.
}
```

Comment: "Member variable does not save value added to it from member from functiion" - in one word: **nonsense**. the problem is almost always something simple. come up with a *short* example.

Comment: Any reason you are using C-style strings (char arrays) as opposed to std::string?

Comment: If you want to use strings in C++, you should use [the standard string class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Answer (score 2):

All of these values, you're writing off the end of the allocated memory:

```
string[13] = '\0';
strStyle[18] = '\0';
area[6] = '\0';
publisher[8] = '\0';
title[8] = '\0';
```

If you want to set the last character to null you do it like this:

```
char string[13];
string[12] = '\0';
```

Because zero-indexed;

Comment: Its still giving me the same output. I tried to modify "area" inside of EAN::read(...); and it keeps the value. But only when its modified inside this member function.

Comment: I suggest creating a much smaller example of the problem, presumbily you can comment out a lot of the logic and still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys thanks for the help i figure it out if you look carefully guys, I called the constructor inside a member function but i for to return what i make that constructor assigns.

so i was missing  `*this = EAN(str, list);`

Thanks for the help guys.